# encrypt nsstring with 3des ios7

Tags: objective-c, 3des

I am  new with iOS7 development and objective c, and i need to develop an application which will send encrypted data with 3DES  to a server,I have searched in stack overflow and Net but still unable to get it work, finally i tried this code but i got null as result,

```
+ (NSString*)encrypt:(NSString*)plainText withKey:(NSString*)key{
    uint8_t keyByte[kSecrectKeyLength];

    NSMutableData *keyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < [key length] / 2; i++) {
        NSString *tempNumber = [key substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i * 2, 2)];
        NSScanner *scanner=[NSScanner scannerWithString:tempNumber];
        unsigned int temp;
        [scanner scanHexInt:&temp];
        Byte B = (Byte)(0xFF & temp);
        keyByte[i] = B;
    }

    NSData* data = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    size_t plainTextBufferSize = [data length];
    const void *vplainText = (const void *)[data bytes];

    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t movedBytes = 0;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);

    const void *vkey = (const void *) keyByte;
    const void *vinitVec = (const void *) [gIv UTF8String];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                       vkey,
                       kCCKeySize3DES,
                       vinitVec,
                       vplainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       &movedBytes);

    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
    //NSString *result = [GTMBase64 stringByEncodingData:myData];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"result=%@",result);

    return result;
}
```

Please have u any idea about the solution???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lol i just struggled with this myself the other day, i have a working solution now using this code

```
+ (NSData *)tripleDesEncryptString:(NSString *)input
                               key:(NSString *)key
                             error:(NSError **)error
{
NSParameterAssert(input);
NSParameterAssert(key);

NSData *inputData = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

size_t outLength;

NSAssert(keyData.length == kCCKeySize3DES, @"the keyData is an invalid size");

NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length  +  kCCBlockSize3DES)];

CCCryptorStatus
result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, // operation
                 kCCAlgorithm3DES, // Algorithm
                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode, // options
                 keyData.bytes, // key
                 keyData.length, // keylength
                 nil,// iv
                 inputData.bytes, // dataIn
                 inputData.length, // dataInLength,
                 outputData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                 outputData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                 &outLength); // dataOutMoved

if (result != kCCSuccess) {
    if (error != NULL) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.your_domain.your_project_name.your_class_name."
                                     code:result
                                 userInfo:nil];
    }
    return nil;
}
[outputData setLength:outLength];
return outputData;
}



+ (NSString *)tripleDesDecryptData:(NSData *)input
                               key:(NSString *)key
                             error:(NSError **)error
{
NSParameterAssert(input);
NSParameterAssert(key);

NSData *inputData = input;
NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

size_t outLength;

NSAssert(keyData.length == kCCKeySize3DES, @"the keyData is an invalid size");

NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length  +  kCCBlockSize3DES)];

CCCryptorStatus
result = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, // operation
                 kCCAlgorithm3DES, // Algorithm
                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode, // options
                 keyData.bytes, // key
                 keyData.length, // keylength
                 nil,// iv
                 inputData.bytes, // dataIn
                 inputData.length, // dataInLength,
                 outputData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                 outputData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                 &outLength); // dataOutMoved

if (result != kCCSuccess) {
    if (error != NULL) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.your_domain.your_project_name.your_class_name."
                                     code:result
                                 userInfo:nil];
    }
    return nil;
}
[outputData setLength:outLength];
return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

you probably want to base64 encode the data the comes out of the encryption method, and then un-base64 anything that you want to decrypt as well, there are built in methods for NSData to do this now, eg:

```
[data base64EncodedDataWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)];
```

to test if the functions work, i used this test function

```
+ (void) testEncryptionAndDecryption {

    NSData *encrypted = [self tripleDesEncryptString:@"test" key:@"123456789123456789123456" error:nil];
    NSLog(@"encrypted data length: %lu", (unsigned long)encrypted.length);
    NSString *decrypted = [self tripleDesDecryptData:encrypted key:@"123456789123456789123456" error:nil];
    NSLog(@"decrypted text: %@", decrypted);
}
```

this gave me the correct output that you would expect

Comment: thank u for ur help, i tries this code, but i didn't get any result, to be more clear, i created a bouton, label and textfeild and in action of the bouton i added this code:

Comment: NSString *msg = self.textdecrypt.text;
    NSString *cle = @"123456789012345678901234";
    NSData *chaine = [[self class] tripleDesEncryptString:msg key:cle error:NULL];
    //NSString* chaine = [self encrypt :msg :cle ];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:chaine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.labelcrypt.text= result;
maybe the problem is in this line:          NSData *chaine = [[self class] tripleDesEncryptString:msg key:cle error:NULL];

Comment: put a break point or print out the length of `chaine`, on the line `NSData *chaine = [[self class] tripleDesEncryptString:msg key:cle error:NULL];` and see if `chaine` actually has data in it, if it does it means it should have worked. this code is currently in an app im working on and it definitely does work.

Comment: ok, i tried it, i added after the line:NSData *chaine = [[self class] .....,this code :  size_t plainTextBufferSize = [chaine length]; NSLog(@"result=%zu",plainTextBufferSize);    and i got resultat=24, that s mean it work, but still no result!!

Comment: Hi, i am back again :(, now the problem is with decrypt, the code look good but when i execute i get break point in this line: if (result != kCCSuccess), i added this code in the action of my bouton to test the decrypt:

Comment: NSString *cle = @"Xm9d7@4Ru&2YaP&?14niO$f%";
    NSString *msg = self.textdecrypt.text;
   
    NSData *chaine = [[self class] tripleDesEncryptString:msg key:cle error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"result=%@",chaine);
    //NSString* chaine = [self encrypt :msg :cle ];
    
    
      NSString *resultat = [[self class] tripleDesDecryptData:chaine key:cle error:NULL];
    
    NSLog(@"result=%@",resultat);
can u show me how u tested the decrypt??

Comment: ill update my answer with a function i used to test the encryption and decryption, you can try it too, but with the code as it stands it works for me

Comment: thanx for ur help, but still same problem i get thread:1 breakpoint:1 in this line: if (result != kCCSuccess) in tripledesdecrypt(), :(

Comment: I solved the problem, by deleting all  breakpoints (cmd+7) :), thanx a lot u saved my life.

Comment: After googled a lot, I finally found this. But my requirement is slightly different from this. My requirement is to 3des encrypt a string and send to server vis POST. Thus a try to convert the output NSData into String. and the following is my code.

`let encryptedData = try TripleDES.tripleDesEncryptString("dddd", key: key)` `let encryptedString = String(data: encryptedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` `print(encryptedData)` . I got a nil output. Can you help with this. I am pretty new to iOS.

Comment: I would give you 100 stars if I could. Your method is the only one that worked for me (had to modify to my needs). Every other similar methods in SO failed for any reason. I've been days fighting with this to get the same 3DES result than the same operation in the android counterpart app. Thanks!

Comment: @rmvz3 glad to have helped :) i struggled with this for a long time too

Comment: @JoeSHI what key are you using for that? did you test your code using the function i provided? they key has to be a very specific length

Comment: I tried using this code for Encryption and Decryption. I am able to encrypt successfully but the decryption is not working properly. kindly help.

Comment: @Imran been a while so im really rusty, but did you try run the `testEncryptionAndDecryption` method i posted in my answer? see if the output looks correct, if it is then its something else going wrong, if the test method not working and you havent edit the code at all, then either something has changed with regards to encryption on ios or i dont know what :?

Comment: I didnot change the code. The encryption worked but decryption doesn't. What do you mean by this in your answer.. un-base64 anything that you want to decrypt ?

Comment: so the encrypting method returns an `NSData` object which isnt too useful if you trying to send it to a server or something, so normally you would base64 encode the data, then when you are trying to decrypt, you would need to undo the base64 encoding so you have an NSData object again to run the decryption on. if you are not doing anything to do with base64 encoding then you shouldnt need to worry about this at all.

Comment: Its working fine now. Your code is still good in 2019. The issue I had was like I was getting base64 data from API. I have to then convert the data to string and then again string to data using NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:plainText options:0]; and then I decrypted the data using the code.

Comment: ah, I was assuming in my example that the data from your api would be a base64 string already, not base64 data (base64 data seems redundant, since the reason to use base64 is to get it to be a string instead of data)